# Docker compose config file not syncing directory properly in Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Scenario**

I use docker-compose for development in NodeJs and MongoDb.
Here is the files structure

```
├── admin
├── backend
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend
└── package-lock.json
```

Here is the content of docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
services:
  swyft-database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: swyft-database
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  swyft-node-server:
    image: node
    container_name: swyft-node-server
    volumes:
      - ./backend :/usr/app/node-services
    working_dir: /usr/app/node-services
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - swyft-database
    depends_on:
      - swyft-database
```

**Problem**

Whenever i run 'docker-compose up' command it creates another 'backend' directory in same directory and fails to execute with following error

```
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! syscall open
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! path /usr/app/node-services/package.json
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! errno -2
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' 
/usr/app/node-services/package.json'
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! enoent 
swyft-node-server    | 
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
swyft-node-server    | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T08_25_24_289Z-debug.log
```

[image: Here you can see backend directory generated by docker-compose]

This is quite bizarre behavior of docker-compose creating same named directory. I believe this has something to do with docker-compose configuration file.

**I am running it on MacOs Catalina**

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the volume as:

```
volumes: 
- backend :/usr/app/node-services
```

So backend (without directory specification ./) would be created in that destination and also check if work_dir is needed alongside Volumes.